# Login register android app cant coonect to local server (connection refused)

Tags: java, android, mysql, ip, connection-refused

This application registers users in a database. When I click the register button, I get `Connection Refused error` in my logs.

My login and register localhost IP is : 127.0.0.1. I searched many websites and articles and they wrote >> you should change 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 but finally I didn't succeed. My emulator is Nox player.

```
    // Server user login url
public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://127.0.0.1:80/android_login_api/login.php";

// Server user register url
public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://127.0.0.1:80/android_login_api/register.php";
```

Comment: Do you have a web server set up on localhost?  Is the web server seeing anything?  Do you have a firewall that might be blocking it?  Please provide more information about your set up.

Comment: You probably have to use 10.0.2.2 or the real IP of your PC because 127.0.0.1 would only refer to your emulated android. Your webserver must also listen on the related interface. Some setups only listen on 127.0.0.1 by default. Change it to 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces. Note that other devices in your network can then access your webserver, too.

Comment: I think, before you try connect, you should use "telnet" to test connect.

Answer (score 1):

**Well !**
Issue can be of the port you are referring to which is `80` in your case. You can try changing the port to `8080`. In that case the Addresses may look like this:

```
    // Server user login url
public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/android_login_api/login.php";

// Server user register url
public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/android_login_api/register.php";
```

Or try like this :

```
// Server user login url
public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android_login_api/login.php";

// Server user register url
public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android_login_api/register.php";
```

**Double check:**

1. Your local host must be up and listening and you should be able to
   hit the url in browser locally (if not then something is wrong with your local server)
2. Check `INTERNET` permission in your Manifest
3. `Port` you are listening to must be `open` for connections.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/android_login_api/register.php in my browser this text opend for me : {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}

Comment: Obviously ! the API you are trying to hit in browser in expecting parameters that need to be passed. Have you tried the same Url from emulator with the parameters provided ?